# How should I learn ML libraries like Sci-kit learn

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I have started learning ML few days ago. I've been following a Udemy course. But I'm not actually feeling comfortable following the tutorial blindly. For example, in data preprocessing part while splitting the dataset into train and test set, they were using a function called train_test_split from sci-kit learn library.

But when I went into their documentation, I couldn't find such function. Then in the video they said it was under model_selection module. But I couldn't find the function there as well. Maybe I'll find it if I go through every single line of that module. But that's also kinda not possible to go through all of those. So, my question is, is it normal or okay to learn like this? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Google is your best friend. First click for "scikit learn train_test_split": [this documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). By the way, it takes less time than to start a question here. ;D

Comment: And yes, it is normal and okay. Getting familiar with documentations and finding the functionalities you are looking for in this way on the web will be important. But that's the learning-by-doing part. If you are only interested in the gists, how-to's and superficial explanations, you can certainly go without. As another note: This is not really the forum to ask such questions, to be honest ... please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use directly the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html). In there you can find also example in which the related functions are used.

For example, for the `train_test_split` method, found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) , there is the method signature, arguments and output explained very well.

Method signature:

```
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(*arrays, test_size=None, train_size=None, random_state=None, shuffle=True, stratify=None)
```

In the same page there is a basic example of the `train_test_split` usage:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# toy dataset
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
# with shuffle
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)
```

Also in the bottom part of the page you can find a lot of examples in which the `train_test_split` is used, usually for toy problems

[image]